# delete row from csv in python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have two different csv file(as success.csv and failure.csv) which contains same column value. I have to delete rows from success.csv if value(msisdn column value) found in error.csv file.

**Success.csv**

```
[root@ngpdn15 MSSuccess]# cat msLogSuccess.csv
MSISDN,REQUEST_ID,STATE1,STATE2,STAETE3,NOTIFICATION
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000037,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
22969000038,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000039,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
```

**failure.csv**

```
MSISDN,REQUEST_ID,STATE1,STATE2,STAETE3,NOTIFICATION
22969000038,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,INPROGRESS,SMS_FAILED,Not send SMS to the subscriber
22969000039,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,FAILURE,Not send SMS to the subscriber
```

In above two file msisdn available in failure.csv are also available in Success.csv so i have to delete entries for these msisdn from success.csv file in python. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a good approach would be using pandas.
You can load the files as pandas DataFrames and then do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
source = pd.read_csv("./success.csv")
failure = pd.read_csv("./failure.csv")
success[~success.MSISDN.isin(failure.MSISDN)]
```

I hope this will help you.